# How to create a drop down menu for indicator parameters

Tags: pine-script

I have checkboxes for paramenters in my code. When you Click settings on the indicator, it looks like this:

Image

[image: 1]

Instead of all these checkboxes, I would like a drop down menu that would allow me to select one 'setting' as shown with the blue circle grouping. How can I do this? Current specific code:

```
// Determine crossover conditions
crossAbove = crossover(slowMA, mid)

bgcolor(color= crossAbove ? color.green : na, transp = 50, title = " Show All Candle Crosses Above S-Line")

// Determine STRONG crossunder conditions
crossBelowStrong = crossunder(slowMA, mid)  and (mid < 50) 

bgcolor(color= crossBelowStrong ? color.red : na, transp = 50,  title = "Show Candle Cross Below S-Line When Below 50" )

// Determine STRONG crossover conditions
crossAboveStrong = crossover(slowMA, mid) and (mid > 50) 

bgcolor(color= crossAboveStrong ? color.green : na, transp = 50, title = "Show Candle Cross Above S-Line When Above 50")

// Determine STRONGEST crossunder conditions
crossBelowStrongest = crossunder(slowMA, mid)  and (mid < 50) and (mid < mid[1])

bgcolor(color= crossBelowStrongest ? color.red : na, transp = 50,  title = "Show Candle Cross Below S-Line, Trending Down & Below 50" )

// Determine STRONGEST crossover conditions
crossAboveStrongest = crossover(slowMA, mid) and (mid > 50) and (mid > mid[1])

bgcolor(color= crossAboveStrongest ? color.green : na, transp = 50, title = "Show Candle Cross Above S-Line, Trending up & Above 50")
```

Thank you!

I've never created a drop down menu to this it totally new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `input.string()` and then pass the options you want to have to its `options` argument.

```
in_op_1 = input.string("Show all candle crosses below S-Line", "Title", ["Show all candle crosses below S-Line", "Show all candle crosses above S-Line"])
```

This would show up as:

[image]

## Edit for v4:

```
in_op_1 = input(defval="Show all candle crosses below S-Line", title="Title", options=["Show all candle crosses below S-Line", "Show all candle crosses above S-Line"], type=input.string)
```

Comment: Thanks for this help. I'm still a little lost as to how I need to input this into the whole code. When I insert this, I get "Compilation error. Line 73: 'input.string' is not a function." I've tried editing the code but I always for that error

Comment: Sorry, it looks like your code is in `v4`. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for you help. That is now appearing in the indicator.  It doesnt seem to change anything though. I still have all of the options in my screenshot above and those checkmarks still seem to determine what is showing. I just want to be able to choose one condition from the dropdown. 

I'm Sorry, I'm trying to learn